# MVC backed auto form generation & editable grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, knockout.js, editablegrid, form-generator

We've been working on web solutions for over past 9+ years and just like many of you, we've migrated from the legacy ASP to ASP.Net, MVC, knockoutjs and so on. jQuery played a keyrole and now it seems its the age of MVVM libraries like KO with declarative data binding based approach.

I'll stop here and ask for expert opinions on our two requirements -

1. **An editable grid** with inbuilt sorting, paging and basic search. And if possible a grid capable of handling its own **editable dialog** (i.e. like datatables.net - but its paid)
2. Is there a way to take the declarative binding to the next level and **auto-generate forms** backed with knockoutjs like data-binding technology.

I believe no need to mention that we're working in ASP.Net v4.0+ and MVC. Most of our forms are backed by one or more table(s) and we can easily manage the backend CRUD operations once the correct actions are triggered from front end and we can have requests serving JSON as and when requested.

*PS: We don't need the old school approachs like the @Html.EditorFor in MVC.*

Comment: Wijmo grid seems pretty nice. http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-complete/grid/ They have free (older) libs: http://wijmo.com/downloads/cdn/
What do you have in mind with auto-generated forms?

Comment: Sir, we've already have got better "paid" plugin libraries like datatables.net and jqwidgets.com. There're lots of open source plugins so a paid plugin could be our last choice. Well, we could let go the automated editable dialog for a worth plugin.